# Linking two different stack navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm trying to link between two different stack navigators and get back to initial state on the first stack from the second stack. Let me know if there is a possible way to do so.

Comment: Hi Tarun, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  What have you tried so far?  Generally, on SO you should show your effort to solve the problem before other people will help you to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. So my route was stack navigator -> tab navigator -> stack navigator. and when I was trying to navigate back to the first stack navigator from the third one I tried passing screen props thinking it would go to the first stack navigator but it ended up going to the tab navigator.

all that I had to do was pass this.props.navigation as screen props from tab navigator.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer the question with so little information, but if you're just looking for a way to reset to the root this should work.

```
navigation.dispatch(
  StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    key: null,
    actions: [
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: routes.ROOT,
      }),
    ],
  })
);
```

Replace `routes.ROOT` with your root route.